# Loading an ontology (owl) using jena and show its graph

Tags: graph, ontology, owl, jena

Im working in a project where I have to load any ontology (is chosen by the user) in .owl language and display its graph as a tree menu. It means the ontology can be any size.

The goal is to show a Taxanomy to be able to classify learning objects.

At the moment, using jena I can load the ontology, but I wonder how to show the graph in a proper way to build the tree menu.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain it better.

Using jena, I can show the Hierarchy using this example: jena.sourceforge.net/examples/class-hierarchy/index.html

With typic pizza example, the jena example shows (more or less, I deleted Anonymous classes):

1. Class :ValuePartition
    1.1 Class :Medium
         1.1.1 Class :Mild
         1.1.2 Class :Hot
    1.2 Class :Spiciness
         1.2.1 Class :Mild
         1.2.2 Class :Medium
         1.2.3 Class :Hot
   ...

When, if you check the ontology pizza in ontologies browser as http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/browser/ (loading the pizza.owl), it is showed:

1. Class :ValuePartition
   1.1 Class :Spiciness
   1.1.1 Class :Mild
   1.1.2 Class :Medium
   1.1.3 Class :Hot 
   ...

I'm using the jena reasoner OWL_MEM_MICRO_RULE_INF, but I tried all of them with no success.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi! It sounds like you need to do the reasoning and then display the ontology as a graph. Check maybe the tutorial http://kill.devc.at/node/84 if it helps. It's a bit out of date but maybe it works...

Answer (score 0):

may be this is a late answer. Give a look at  prefuse package at http://prefuse.org/

Herli Menezes